# battery charge stops at 99%

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery

My phone is Kyocera Hydro Icon, running Android 4.4

After using it for almost a year, recently charging its battery stops at 99%, indicated by the battery icon and the corresponding LED staying red instead of turning green.

Is it normal or there might be some problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try leaving it on charge for a while, say 10 minutes after hitting 99% , to see if it charges fully?

Comment: I left it charging over night, for several nights.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it normal or there might be some problem?

It is not normal but it is not a cause for concern as long as the battery performance is not visibly degraded

- Li Ion batteries have different stages of charging as shown in [Fig.1](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries). What is probably happening in your case is that the required voltage levels to fully charge the battery are not being attained despite prolonged charging. As a result the LED and battery levels are not reflecting fully charged condition. This is probably due to the charger/ cable combo not delivering voltage/ current as required. This can be verified by changing them.
- It is *not a cause for concern*, since it is not a good practice to fully charge . Quoting from same source

> Li-ion does not need to be fully charged as is the case with lead acid, nor is it desirable to do so. In fact, it is better not to fully charge because a high voltage stresses the battery

Comment: Both at home and in office, charging stops at 99%.

Comment: Ok. Another possibility is that the battery has lost capacity to hold full charge, i have experienced that but don't have any sources to quote. But having full charge is not advised as mentioned

Comment: *Bump charging*- discharge for a few minutes at 99%,  charge again and repeat this process few times. By this battery is said to hold maximum charge possible. Not advised for regular use